# Android Errors after adding Scringo Library

Tags: android, android-library, httpconnection

after include Scringo library in my project, implementing the QuickStart instructions :

```
private Scringo scringo;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    Scringo.setAppId("<MY_SCRINGO_APP_ID>");
    scringo = new Scringo(this);
    scringo.init();
    scringo.addSidebar();


}

@Override
protected void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    scringo.onStart();
}

@Override
protected void onStop() {
    super.onStop();
    scringo.onStop();
}
```

I merge the Manifest.xml for permissions and set new button to open Scringo menu.
After Running the app, when clicking the button to open Scringo Menu, I getting Errors:

```
    12-21 18:59:31.275: E/Scringo(5573):    at libcore.net.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getInputStream(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:168)
12-21 18:59:31.275: E/Scringo(5573):    at libcore.net.http.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getInputStream(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:271)
12-21 18:59:31.275: E/Scringo(5573):    at com.scringo.utils.ScringoHttpFetcher.getResponseStr(ScringoHttpFetcher.java:132)
12-21 18:59:31.275: E/Scringo(5573):    at com.scringo.utils.ScringoJsonFetcher.handleResponse(ScringoJsonFetcher.java:59)
12-21 18:59:31.275: E/Scringo(5573):    at com.scringo.utils.ScringoJsonFetcher.run(ScringoJsonFetcher.java:40)
12-21 18:59:31.275: E/Scringo(5573): Caused by: libcore.io.GaiException: getaddrinfo failed: EAI_NODATA (No address associated with hostname)
12-21 18:59:31.275: E/Scringo(5573):    at libcore.io.Posix.getaddrinfo(Native Method)
12-21 18:59:31.275: E/Scringo(5573):    at libcore.io.ForwardingOs.getaddrinfo(ForwardingOs.java:55)
12-21 18:59:31.275: E/Scringo(5573):    at java.net.InetAddress.lookupHostByName(InetAddress.java:405)
12-21 18:59:31.275: E/Scringo(5573):    ... 18 more
12-21 18:59:31.275: E/Scringo(5573): Caused by: libcore.io.ErrnoException: getaddrinfo failed: EACCES (Permission denied)
12-21 18:59:31.275: E/Scringo(5573):    ... 21 more
12-21 18:59:31.275: E/Scringo(5573): Error fetching
12-21 18:59:31.275: E/Scringo(5573): java.lang.SecurityException: Permission denied (missing INTERNET permission?)
12-21 18:59:31.275: E/Scringo(5573):    at java.net.InetAddress.lookupHostByName(InetAddress.java:418)
12-21 18:59:31.275: E/Scringo(5573):    at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByNameImpl(InetAddress.java:236)
12-21 18:59:31.275: E/Scringo(5573):    at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:214)
12-21 18:59:31.275: E/Scringo(5573):    at libcore.net.http.HttpConnection.<init>(HttpConnection.java:70)
12-21 18:59:31.275: E/Scringo(5573):    at libcore.net.http.HttpConnection.<init>(HttpConnection.java:50)
12-21 18:59:31.275: E/Scringo(5573):    at libcore.net.http.HttpConnection$Address.connect(HttpConnection.java:340)
12-21 18:59:31.275: E/Scringo(5573):    at libcore.net.http.HttpConnectionPool.get(HttpConnectionPool.java:87)
12-21 18:59:31.275: E/Scringo(5573):    at libcore.net.http.HttpConnection.connect(HttpConnection.java:128)
12-21 18:59:31.275: E/Scringo(5573):    at libcore.net.http.HttpEngine.openSocketConnection(HttpEngine.java:315)
12-21 18:59:31.275: E/Scringo(5573):    at libcore.net.http.HttpsURLConnectionImpl$HttpsEngine.makeSslConnection(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:461)
12-21 18:59:31.275: E/Scringo(5573):    at libcore.net.http.HttpsURLConnectionImpl$HttpsEngine.connect(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:433)
12-21 18:59:31.275: E/Scringo(5573):    at libcore.net.http.HttpEngine.sendSocketRequest(HttpEngine.java:289)
12-21 18:59:31.275: E/Scringo(5573):    at libcore.net.http.HttpEngine.sendRequest(HttpEngine.java:239)
12-21 18:59:31.275: E/Scringo(5573):    at libcore.net.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getResponse(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:273)
12-21 18:59:31.275: E/Scringo(5573):    at libcore.net.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getInputStream(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:168)
12-21 18:59:31.275: E/Scringo(5573):    at libcore.net.http.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getInputStream(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:271)
12-21 18:59:31.275: E/Scringo(5573):    at com.scringo.utils.ScringoHttpFetcher.getResponseStr(ScringoHttpFetcher.java:132)
12-21 18:59:31.275: E/Scringo(5573):    at com.scringo.utils.ScringoJsonFetcher.handleResponse(ScringoJsonFetcher.java:59)
12-21 18:59:31.275: E/Scringo(5573):    at com.scringo.utils.ScringoJsonFetcher.run(ScringoJsonFetcher.java:40)
12-21 18:59:31.275: E/Scringo(5573): Caused by: libcore.io.GaiException: getaddrinfo failed: EAI_NODATA (No address associated with hostname)
12-21 18:59:31.275: E/Scringo(5573):    at libcore.io.Posix.getaddrinfo(Native Method)
12-21 18:59:31.275: E/Scringo(5573):    at libcore.io.ForwardingOs.getaddrinfo(ForwardingOs.java:55)
12-21 18:59:31.275: E/Scringo(5573):    at java.net.InetAddress.lookupHostByName(InetAddress.java:405)
12-21 18:59:31.275: E/Scringo(5573):    ... 18 more
12-21 18:59:31.275: E/Scringo(5573): Caused by: libcore.io.ErrnoException: getaddrinfo failed: EACCES (Permission denied)
12-21 18:59:31.275: E/Scringo(5573):    ... 21 more
12-21 18:59:34.305: E/Scringo(5573): Error fetching
12-21 18:59:34.305: E/Scringo(5573): java.lang.SecurityException: Permission denied (missing INTERNET permission?)
12-21 18:59:34.305: E/Scringo(5573):    at java.net.InetAddress.lookupHostByName(InetAddress.java:418)
12-21 18:59:34.305: E/Scringo(5573):    at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByNameImpl(InetAddress.java:236)
12-21 18:59:34.305: E/Scringo(5573):    at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:214)
12-21 18:59:34.305: E/Scringo(5573):    at libcore.net.http.HttpConnection.<init>(HttpConnection.java:70)
12-21 18:59:34.305: E/Scringo(5573):    at libcore.net.http.HttpConnection.<init>(HttpConnection.java:50)
12-21 18:59:34.305: E/Scringo(5573):    at libcore.net.http.HttpConnection$Address.connect(HttpConnection.java:340)
12-21 18:59:34.305: E/Scringo(5573):    at libcore.net.http.HttpConnectionPool.get(HttpConnectionPool.java:87)
12-21 18:59:34.305: E/Scringo(5573):    at libcore.net.http.HttpConnection.connect(HttpConnection.java:128)
12-21 18:59:34.305: E/Scringo(5573):    at libcore.net.http.HttpEngine.openSocketConnection(HttpEngine.java:315)
12-21 18:59:34.305: E/Scringo(5573):    at libcore.net.http.HttpsURLConnectionImpl$HttpsEngine.makeSslConnection(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:461)
12-21 18:59:34.305: E/Scringo(5573):    at libcore.net.http.HttpsURLConnectionImpl$HttpsEngine.connect(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:433)
12-21 18:59:34.305: E/Scringo(5573):    at libcore.net.http.HttpEngine.sendSocketRequest(HttpEngine.java:289)
12-21 18:59:34.305: E/Scringo(5573):    at libcore.net.http.HttpEngine.sendRequest(HttpEngine.java:239)
12-21 18:59:34.305: E/Scringo(5573):    at libcore.net.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getResponse(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:273)
12-21 18:59:34.305: E/Scringo(5573):    at libcore.net.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getInputStream(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:168)
12-21 18:59:34.305: E/Scringo(5573):    at libcore.net.http.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getInputStream(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:271)
12-21 18:59:34.305: E/Scringo(5573):    at com.scringo.utils.ScringoHttpFetcher.getResponseStr(ScringoHttpFetcher.java:132)
12-21 18:59:34.305: E/Scringo(5573):    at com.scringo.utils.ScringoJsonFetcher.handleResponse(ScringoJsonFetcher.java:59)
12-21 18:59:34.305: E/Scringo(5573):    at com.scringo.utils.ScringoJsonFetcher.run(ScringoJsonFetcher.java:40)
12-21 18:59:34.305: E/Scringo(5573): Caused by: libcore.io.GaiException: getaddrinfo failed: EAI_NODATA (No address associated with hostname)
12-21 18:59:34.305: E/Scringo(5573):    at libcore.io.Posix.getaddrinfo(Native Method)
12-21 18:59:34.305: E/Scringo(5573):    at libcore.io.ForwardingOs.getaddrinfo(ForwardingOs.java:55)
12-21 18:59:34.305: E/Scringo(5573):    at java.net.InetAddress.lookupHostByName(InetAddress.java:405)
12-21 18:59:34.305: E/Scringo(5573):    ... 18 more
12-21 18:59:34.305: E/Scringo(5573): Caused by: libcore.io.ErrnoException: getaddrinfo failed: EACCES (Permission denied)
12-21 18:59:34.305: E/Scringo(5573):    ... 21 more
.
.
.
```

Please Help...

Answer (score 2):

Check the logs more carefully, you will see that you need to add INTERNET permission to your AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

Comment: This is not the problem...
I added the internet permissions and double check to see if this is the issue.
Any other ideas?

Comment: @MuliBachar Please copy-paste that manifest part to the question. This is the most likely reason, and it won't work if there's even a single typo in the permission name.

Answer (score 1):

When you set the Scringo Project Library as a dependency of your project, and set the `manifestmerger.enabled=true` in the project.properties, it merges your manifest with the Scringo manifest. In the Scringo manifest, the INTERNET permission is already added. If there was some kind of error in the merge, you'll see it in the Eclipse Console.

The merged manifest should be in your bin folder, take a look there to see if it was merged correctly and if the INTERNET permission exists there.

BTW, sometimes "cleaning" the project helps ;-)